# Can I create a "symlink-esque" file to "merge" two files together?

Tags: unix, filesystems, symbolic-link

I'm dealing with an application that reads a config file, `config.yml`, from the current directory. This config file contains both secret information (API keys) that shouldn't be checked in to source control, and other configuration information that can be.

What I'd like to do is to split this config file in two, to have `config.secret.yml` and `config.public.yml`. `config.secret.yml` will be ignored by source control, while `config.public.yml` can be checked in.

Then, I want to somehow create a `config.yml` file-like object that effectively "symlinks" the concatenated contents of `config.secret.yml` and `config.public.yml`, so that this happens:

```
> cat config.secret.yml
---
:api_key: 2712ab206a8003e44b2a84c467fc1b58
>
> cat config.public.yml    
:site_id: 123
>
> cat config.yml
---
:api_key: 2712ab206a8003e44b2a84c467fc1b58
:site_id: 123
```

I'm aware that symlinks themselves don't support this sort of behaviour, and that one would usually have both "default" and "local" settings read from the application side, but let's work under the assumption that only a single configuration file can be read.

The file is read by Ruby's `File.read()` method and parsed by `YAML.load()` if that provides any opportunity for cunning hacks.

Comment: Is it a requirement to read using `File.read()`? Otherwise You could do something like `file_data = system("cat file1 file2")` (untested)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @zelanix, but unfortunately I'm working on the assumption that I can't alter the source of the application reading the file.

Comment: I would assume this would require some sort of iffy kernel hack, but should that not turn out to be the case, I'd love to know. +1 for interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a named pipe for this.

As a sample:

```
echo foo > file1
echo bar > file2
```

then create a new script in the same directory as follows:

**combine.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -p foobar ] && rm foobar

trap "[ -p foobar ] && rm foobar && exit" SIGINT

while [  true ]; do
  mkfifo foobar
  echo "Writing File"
  cat file1 file2 > foobar
  rm foobar
done
```

Then

```
chmod +x combine.sh
./combine.sh
```

This will create a pipe named `foobar` in the same directory. You can now read from this pipe from any process as if it were a real file.

For example, in a separate terminal:

```
$ cat foobar
foo
bar
```

Of course you could then run this in the background using `./combine.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null &` or run it as a service if you need greater persistence.

Comment: Thanks @zelanix. Obviously was hoping that it might be possible without having to run a script / ongoing process, but I'm guessing this is probably the best that one can do :).

Comment: Yeah, I know @GavinBallard, completely agree that that would be nicer. If you find anything then please post back here! I would definitely be interested to know. I will ponder it too.